# Netty ChannelRead() was not invoked and writeAndFlush() not work

Tags: java, netty, rpc

I implemented RPC using Netty, however, `channelRead()` in **RPCClientHandler.java** could not be invoked. Additionally, `writeAndFlush()` also not worked in `call()` of **RPCClientHandler.java** unless I invoked `writeAndFlush()` again somewhere else, for example, in **ServiceProxy.java**. I guess there might be something wrong in **ServiceProxy.java** of the *Client Side*.

*Client Side*

**RPCClient.java**

```
package rpc.client;
//omit import

public class RPCClient {
public String methodA(String message){
    String protocol="send?";
    IUserService s = (IUserService) new ServiceProxy().getProxy(IUserService.class, protocol);
    return s.say(message); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("client result："+new RPCClient().methodA("Aloha")); //not print
    System.out.println("client result："+new RPCClient().methodA("Ola")); //not print
}
}
```

**RPCClientHandler.java**

```
package rpc.clientstub;
//omit import

 public class RPCClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter implements Callable {
private ChannelHandlerContext context; 
private String response;
@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
public synchronized void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("invoked success"); // not print 
    response = msg.toString();
    System.out.println("invoked success"+response); //not print also
    notify();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    ctx.close();
}

}
public synchronized Object call() throws Exception {
    ChannelFuture cf = context.writeAndFlush("Ack");
    System.out.println(cf);  //print:DefaultChannelPromise@113904e2(incomplete)
    System.out.println("invoked1, ctx is: "+context); //print
    wait();
    System.out.println("invoked2"); //not print
    return response;
}
}
```

**ServiceProxy.java**

```
package rpc.clientstub;
//omit import here

public class ServiceProxy {
private static ExecutorService executor
        = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
private static RPCClientHandler clientHandler;

public Object getProxy(Class<?> serviceClass, String protocol){
    return Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class<?>[]{serviceClass}, new InvocationHandler() { 
                @Override
                public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                    if(clientHandler == null) {
                        startClient();
                        System.out.println("clientHandler exists:" + clientHandler);
                    }
                    return executor.submit(clientHandler).get();

                }
            });
    }

public static void startClient() throws Exception{ 
    clientHandler = new RPCClientHandler();
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
    try{
        bootstrap.group(group)
                 .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                 .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                     @Override
                     protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                         ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                         ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
                         ch.pipeline().addLast(clientHandler);
                     }
                 });
        ChannelFuture cf = bootstrap.connect("127.0.0.1", 8890).sync();
        cf.channel().writeAndFlush("DDD");  //for example, only I invoked writeAndFlush here, message could be seen from server side

    } finally{
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }

}
}
```

*Server Side*

**RPCServer.java**

```
public class RPCServer {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    startServer();
}
public static void startServer() {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try{
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup,workerGroup)
                       .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                       .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                           @Override
                           protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                               ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringDecoder());
                               ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());
                               ch.pipeline().addLast(new RPCServerHandler());
                           }
                       });
        ChannelFuture cf = serverBootstrap.bind(8890).sync();
        System.out.println("provider is running");
        cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
}
```

**RPCServerHandler.java**

```
public class RPCServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("msg in channelRead:" + msg +"the class of msg is:" + msg.getClass());   
    if(msg.toString().startsWith("send?")){
            String res = new UserServiceImpl().say(msg.toString().substring(msg.toString().lastIndexOf("?")+1));
            ctx.writeAndFlush(res);              
    }
}
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
    ctx.close();
}
}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {
public String say(String message){
   System.out.println("called");
   if(message != null){
       return "##RECEIVED MESSAGE from client:"+message;
   } else{
       return "##RECEIVED NOTHING";
   }
}
}
```